# How to Cluster words and phrases with pre-trained model on Gensim

Tags: gensim, word2vec

What I want exactly is to cluster words and phrases, e.g.
knitting/knit loom/loom knitting/weaving loom/rainbow loom/home decoration accessories/loom knit/knitting loom/...And I don'd have corpus while I have only the words/phrases. Could I use a pre-trained model like the one from GoogleNews/Wikipedia/... to realise it?

I am trying now to use Gensim to load GoogleNews pre-trained model to get phrases similarity. I've been told that The GoogleNews model includes vectors of phrases and words. But I find that I could only get word-similarity while phrase-similarity fails with an error message that the phrase is not in the vocabulary. Please advise me. Thank you.

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

GOOGLE_MODEL = '../GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'

model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(GOOGLE_MODEL, binary=True) 


# done well
model.most_similar("computer", topn=3) 

# done with error message "computer_software" is not in the vocabulory.
model.most_similar("computer_software", topn=3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GoogleNews` set does include many multi-word phrases, as created via some statistical analysis, but might not include something specific you're hoping it does, like `'computer_software'`.

On the other hand, I see an online word-list suggesting that a phrase like `'composite_fillings'` **is** in the `GoogleNews` vocabulary, so this will likely work for you:

```
model.most_similar("composite_fillings", topn=3)
```

With that vector-set, you're limited to what they chose to model as phrases. If you need similarly-strong vectors for other phrases, you'd likely need to train your own model, on a corpus where the phrases important to you have been combined into single tokens. (If you just need something-better-than-nothing, averaging together the constituent words' word-vectors would give you something to work with... but that's a pretty-crude stand-in for truly modeling the bigram/multigram against its unique contexts.)

Comment: Hi, gojomo, thanks for your suggestion. And I have added more detailes to the question in the first paragraph. Do you have any idea about it? Thanks again. @gojimo

Comment: Are there any more pre-trained models available on the Internet? Free or not.

Comment: The `GoogleNews` word-vectors will only be useful for phrases that they chose to recognize and create word-vectors for. If they didn't, there won't be a word-vector for the phrase. (And, as noted in my answer, a crude approximation like "average the individual word word-vectors together" is unlikely to be satisfactory.) If you have your own project-specific ideas of which phrases are important, you'll likely need to acquire your own corpus and train your own model.

Comment: There are other pre-trained word-vector sets, but they each are limited to their creators' chosen words/phrases. (The `GoogleNews` set is one of the largest and earliest, but quite old by now.) Some are in a format compatible for loading by plain w2v `gensim` (even if trained another way, like GloVe vectors at https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/), while others rely on code/algorithms with other features, like FastText (as from https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html - which gensim can load using other classes). But again, their phrase choices are unlikely to match your needs.