# Could I use BERT to Cluster phrases with pre-trained model

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, pytorch, gensim, word2vec

I found it was a failure that I had used Gensim with GoogleNews pre-trained model to cluster phrases like:

- knitting
- knit loom
- loom knitting
- weaving loom
- rainbow loom
- home decoration accessories
- loom knit/knitting loom
- ...

I am advised that [GoogleNews model does't have the phrases in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426745/how-to-cluster-words-and-phrases-with-pre-trained-model-on-gensim). The phrases I have are a little specific to GoogleNews model while I don't have corpus to train a new model. I have only the phrases. And now I am considering to turn to BERT. But could BERT do that as I expected as above? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! In order for people to help you, it would be great if you could give a little more detail. What are you trying to achieve? Do you know the phrases you want to cluster on already? Why do you not have a corpus - i.e. where do the phrases come from? What do you want to do with the clusters once you have them? Code examples (input, output, expected output) are also really useful. BERT is pretty advanced and powerful, and might prove to be overkill. (Also, if your other question has been answered by @gojomo, don't forget to accept the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed a phrase into the pretrained BERT model and get an embedding, i.e. a fixed-dimension vector. So BERT can embed your phrases in a space. Then you can use a clustering algorithm (such as k-means) to cluster the phrases. The phrases do not need to occur in the training corpus of BERT, as long as the words they consist of are in the vocabulary. You will have to try to see if the embeddings give you relevant results.